# table and page break inside list

Tags: tables, lists, page-breaking

For a cooperative latex document with a lot of authors, it was decided to use tables for certain structures. Therefore, I have to cope with the problem of automatic page breaks of tables that only consist of 1 column and several rows. The column often contain different lists. The attached example shows the problem: The table does not break within a list. Is there a way to work around this issue?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{\textwidth}|}
\hline
\blindtext[1]\\
\blindtext[2]\\\hline
\begin{compactenum}
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\end{compactenum}\\
\blindtext[2]
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of having a one column longtable?

Comment: Not very useful, I know. But decided by the coordinator and everyone is working with it now.

Comment: No single longtable cell can be split across pages.

Comment: This is what I experienced an described in the example above. Any other ideas to work around this problem?

Comment: Rather than `longtable`, I'd suggest `mdframed`.

Comment: @egreg How about writing a short answer?

Answer (score 2):

A table cell cannot be split across pages; there might be some magic trick, but a one column `longtable` seems inappropriate. In order to get a frame the package `mdframed` seems to be a better choice.